# navigation active link background changing on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a navigation div like below, but when I mouse over the active link it still gets a grey background instead of red background. How can I change this? I don't want to change red background of active link.

```css
    #navigation ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    #navigation li {
      float: left;
    }

    #navigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    }

    #navigation .active,
    #navigation .active:hover {
    background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
only a single line change,

```css
#navigation ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    #navigation li {
      float: left;
    }

    #navigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    }

    #navigation .active a,
    #navigation .active:hover a{
    background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

you can also use `:not(.active) a` insted of `#navigation .active a`

Answer (score 1):

With your active styles you're targeting the `li`, rather than the `a`. Add the `a` to your selectors:

```
#navigation .active a,
#navigation .active a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: sorry its saying i dont have enough reputation. once i get 15 i will upwote

Answer (score 0):

To change the hover to red, apply it to `#navigation li a:hover` where you're currently setting grey.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
#navigation li a:hover {
background-color: grey;
}
```

to

```
#navigation li a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the `#navigation .active,` from the first part of the CSS and see if it works then. You can probably remove the `#navigation` as well since there's only 1 instance of the `.active` class.